# Jenkins plugin Klocwork : Error occurred during build: Authentication failed

Tags: authentication, jenkins, klocwork

I'm running Klocwork analysis with Jenkins on a windows server 2019.
Jenkins                   : 2.235.1
Klocwork Analysis Plug-in : 2020.3.

when the job is executing klockwork command (kwbuildproject, kwdeploy), there is authentication error :

```
Authentication failed. Please run the "C:\Klocwork\Server 18.2\bin\kwauth.exe --url https://<my-URL>/" command to login.
```

Of course, I ran kwauth.exe, and the klockwork commands run fine from command line on server.
The problem is that when run by the plugin, the authentication fails (or no credential provided - it's not visible in log)

I tried to use explicit ltoken configuration, and it's detected by the plugin

```
Detected ltoken file. Setting KLOCWORK_LTOKEN to "C:\Users\<my-USER>\.klocwork\ltoken"
```

But still, same authentication error.

On an older Jenkins (Plugin Klocwork Analysis 1.18), the authentication works using same ltoken file.

Do I miss something in the configuration of Klocwork plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the Klocwork analysis from the command line as X user and trying to run the Jenkins Job as Y user? if yes, you should authenticate the Y user as well through kwauth. Y user should have access to perform Klocwork analysis (Roles).
Please Make sure the ltoken file can be accessed by Jenkins.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30459355)